# RecyclerView does not show all items inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

**The problem**

In my `Activity` I initialize a `Fragment`, which contains a `RecyclerView`. But I've recognized that it is not displaying all items. That means instead of 14 it only shows 11 items. In addition the last visible item (number 12) is cutted off

**My Implementation**

The `Activity` contains an empty `FrameLayout` that acts as the `Fragment` container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res./android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#e0e0e0">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border_white"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/footer_padding">

    <include layout="@layout/footer"></include>

</LinearLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/layout_footer"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the RecyclerView in the Fragment:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#e0e0e0"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_header"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/startpage_padding"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <include layout="@layout/header"></include>

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/startpage_margin"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_header"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_loading_indicator"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/startpage_progressbar"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/startpage_progressbar"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_error_message_display"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/startpage_text_padding"
        android:text="@string/error_message"
        android:textSize="@dimen/startpage_text"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Solving Approaches**

I've already tried it with `match_parent` in the `RecyclerView` and also added a `paddingBottom` to it. With paddingBottom="30dp" one more element is visible but that's not a good solution. Furthermore my `Activity` is using the `AlertDialog`-Theme which is setted in the `Manifest`. Removing it shows the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change  `android:layout_above="@id/layout_footer"` to  `android:layout_above="@+id/layout_footer"` Also why are you using `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_header"` for `RecyclerView`

Comment: Thanks for the hint but that didn't help. I'm using `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_header"` for positioning because the `RecyclerView` is inside a `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: What is the parent view of the RecyclerView?

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu I edited my post.

Comment: Not quite sure what the problem is, but can you try using a RelativeLayout instead of a ConstraintLayout so we you can see the difference?

Comment: actually u used the constraint layout in incorrect way

Comment: I ll just post my xml version

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I finally fixed it. The problem was the `wrap_content` in my `RecyclerView` inside `ConstraintLayout`. By using `wrap_content` for the height of the `RecyclerView` the parent cuts the bottom of it off. So you have to use 0dp for the height and a constraintBottom.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/startpage_margin"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_header"/>
```

Comment: I also had to change from ScrollView to android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView (if using a scroll layout).

Comment: Dear god I also had this issue spent several hour on it. Had match parent on the item view, of course I couldn't see the rest.. Such a rookie mistake, thanks!

Comment: Using NestedScrollView and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` worked for me. I didn't need to change to `0dp`.

Comment: @Deni Agureo, Hi, Do you an explanation why wrap_content doesn't work for layout_height in **RecyclerView**? or it just one of the Illnesses of Android that no one can explain?

Comment: Three hours of trying to figure this out, and I found this lifesaver!

Answer (score 2):

try to change your xml to following, as constraint layout wraps spaces when used in incorrect way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#e0e0e0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <include layout="@layout/support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/startpage_margin"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_below="+id/layout_header"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_loading_indicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_error_message_display"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Error"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used wrap_content for the height but the bottom of the recycleview still scrolled off bottom of the screen so that the last item was not visible.  I resorted to using a finagled solution of adding a bottom padding on the recyclerview until the last item was visible